# Is it possible to call a class attribute by using a variable which has a valid attribute name?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am a newbie in Object Oriented Programming. The problem might sound silly.

I have a class named Dogs(). And this class has some instances age, height, weight which are stored in the database.

```
class Dogs():
    age=IntegerField()
    height=FloatField()
    weight=FloatField()
```

Now if I call the class in a variable and then call the instances with the name inside the class it works fine.

```
dog=Dogs.objects.all()[0]

dog.age #works fine
dog.height #works fine
dog.weight #works fine
```

Now I have another variable which contains one of the instance's name say **(temp='age')**. I want to call the instance (which is in the variable temp) of the class Dogs using the variable.

```
dog.temp #Does not work
```

Is it possible to get the instance by calling with the variable? If yes then how should I do it? If no then what should be my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```py
getattr(dog, temp)
```